# in postgres, ORDER BY seems not to work in recursive cte

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

In the cte select, I'm concatenating fixed-size id as a sort key:

```
with recursive cte(
        uno_id,
        uno_tp,
        pnt_uno_id,
        status,
        title,
        content,
        sorter,
        depth ) 
as( select
        uno.uno_id,
        uno.uno_tp,
        uno.pnt_uno_id,
        uno.status,
        uno.title,
        uno.content,
        uno.uno_id::text,
        1
from    uno
where   uno.uno_id = \$1 

union all

select  uno.uno_id,
        uno.uno_tp,
        uno.pnt_uno_id,
        uno.status,
        uno.title,
        uno.content,
        cte.sorter || '-' || uno.uno_id::text,
        cte.depth + 1 AS depth
from    uno 
join    cte ON uno.pnt_uno_id = cte.uno_id
    )
select  *
from    cte
order   by sorter;
```

and here is a listing showing the `uno_id` and the `sorter` column:

```
1152288185909250, 1152288185909250
1158885255675908, 1152288185909250-1158885255675908
1158885255675906, 1152288185909250-1158885255675906
1158885255675907, 1152288185909250-1158885255675906-1158885255675907
```

As you can see the second row is out of place - it should actually the the last row.

How can I fix this?

---

NEVER MIND.  Postgres was working correctly.  The transport between the server and client did not maintain correct ordering of the array.

Sorry about the unnecessary head scratching and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some kind of misunderstanding. Something that is not in your question.
Consider the following demo:

```
WITH cte (uno_id, sorter) AS (
    VALUES
      ('1158885255675908'::text, '1152288185909250-1158885255675908'::text)
     ,('1152288185909250', '1152288185909250')
     ,('1158885255675907', '1152288185909250-1158885255675906-1158885255675907')
     ,('1158885255675906', '1152288185909250-1158885255675906')
    )
SELECT  *
FROM    cte
ORDER   BY sorter;
```

Result as expected:

```
      uno_id      |                       sorter
------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 1152288185909250 | 1152288185909250
 1158885255675906 | 1152288185909250-1158885255675906
 1158885255675907 | 1152288185909250-1158885255675906-1158885255675907
 1158885255675908 | 1152288185909250-1158885255675908
```

This sort order works for `any` version of PostgreSQL. (The CTE needs v8.4+.)

Comment: when running your test case get `syntax error at or near "x"` - am unfamiliar with neat apparently trick of using VALUES in SELECT statement

Comment: please ignore last comment - not enough coffee.  same results for your testing.  more looking needed on my part.